# Try catch a popup window in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, popup

I am using an `<iframe>` to load a custom url scheme on mobile device.

The goal is that when my app is installed, the app loads. When it is not installed though, I'd like to display something to suggest to download the app and redirect to the appstore.

This trick has been working fine on most browser except safari on iphone, where I get a popup saying "Cannot Open Page because the address is invalid".
I'd really like to get rid of this popup and I tried the following (in javscript):

- Try/catch before appending element to see if the popup triggers an error (fail, probably because a popup isn't a javascript error)
- Setting "onload" / "onunload" / "onerror" event listeners (fail)
- simulating a tap to dismiss the popup (fail)

Any strategies / suggestions on how to handle this?